# How to auto login in react using @react-oauth/google

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement a google SSO login in my react.js application. Signing in part is working as expected and I'm getting a JWT in the response callback, but as soon as I refresh the page I have to login again to get the JWT. I was previously using react-google-login npm package that used to sign in the user automatically and return the user object on page refresh, but that isn't happening with the new @react-oauth/google package.

This is how the button element looks like

```
    <GoogleLogin
        theme="filled_blue"
        text="continue_with"
        auto_select={true}
        useOneTap={true}
        state_cookie_domain='single_host_origin'
        onSuccess={(credentialResponse) => {
          console.log(credentialResponse);
        }}
        onError={() => {
          console.log("Login Failed");
        }}
      />
```

Please help me out, how can I persist a user login automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the login token in a cookie or on the local storage.
[Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)